# Is there any clear, entry level documentation available for boost-spirit?

Tags: c++, documentation, boost-spirit

I've tried to wade through the official documentation on the Boost Spirit page, but I find it completely unintelligible (despite 25+ years programming experience and an English Language degree) -- it's clearly written by somebody who knows the system well (good) but assumes that the reader also knows the system well (bad). I need something that won't throw sentences like

> Parsers and generators in Spirit are fully attributed

clearly a meaning of "attributed" I am unaware of, and a web search doesn't help. Or

> Sequences require an attribute type to expose the concept of a fusion sequence, where all elements of that fusion sequence have to be compatible with the corresponding element of the component sequence

What is a fusion sequence? The only one I know is happening in the Sun. How in C++ does one "expose" a "concept"?

Are there any good tutorials describing Boost Spirit from a beginner's perspective?

Comment: Good luck with that.  I've found most of Boost's documentation to be...  lacking.

Comment: A "fusion sequence" is an object that conforms to the [Sequence Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence.html) from `boost::fusion`.

Comment: I once tried to learn boost.spirit, and gave up for exactly this reason. And after all, I do not regret it: 1) it is *limited* (better using real parser generators. Actually in the time I could spend learning it I *wrote my own parser generator from scratch*), 2) it is ugly (I oppose the abuse of C++ for DSL), and 3) people who use it complain for terribly slow compile times...

Comment: @JohnDibling Can you explain what it lacks? In my experience there are few libraries with such [comprehensive documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) (both plumbing and porcelain). Perhaps, what you are looking for is more [samples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/)?

Comment: @ybungalobill Completely agree there: you got to pick your tools for the job. I love Spirit because it's fun, it's "builtin", and it's taught me heaps about generic programming in C++. But I'd hesitate multiple times before including it in any long-term project.

Comment: @sehe I can't answer for John, but I can say what I think it lacks: an entry route.

The documentation certainly seems excellent, but it's documentation for insiders. That's fine, usually the first level of documentation that produced, and it seems to have been done well. But it assumes extensive knowledge of the rest of the Boost library and of parsers. I've already had to learn two other Boost libraries, and from Mankarse's comment it seems I'm going to have to learn another. Is there a dependency tree of the libraries I need to know (to use it, not the under-the-bonnet dependencies)?

Comment: There are [several articles](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/) on www.boost-spirit.com. The ones in the [Attribute handling](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/) section explain (or at least give context to) your first issue. I have also found very interesting articles in the [Tips of the day](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/tips-of-the-day/) section.

Comment: I suggest that you first try a strongly typed functional language like Haskell or one of the ML family (might be easier to cope with if you're coming from the traditional imperative languages school). Once you get a good grip on the concept of type inference, type polymorphism (in the academic sense), and other more exotic concepts, then the spirit way of describing things might become a bit more decipherable.

Comment: @didierc No, that's not the problem. I have a background in formal methods and am reasonably fluent in OCAML -- I can do FP.

Comment: @digitig sorry for the noise then :)

Comment: @didierc: Eliminating the plausible but wrong is an essential part of diagnosing a problem. It wasn't noise! Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this documentation to be a good read for Boost.

http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/parser.html

Comment: That documentation refers to the "classic" version of spirit.

Comment: How much difference does it make that it's the "classic" version? Would it still make a useful entry point?

Comment: I would think at the very least the conceptual explanations would be useful.